# DragonBoard 410c create custom Windows 10 IoT Core image

Tags: windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10, bsp, dragonboard

After reading the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/create-a-basic-image) about creating a custom Image for Windows 10 IoT Core, I'm totally overwhelmed. I installed the required tools, got the BSP for the DragonBoard 410c and started step by step from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/create-a-basic-image)

I was very unseccessful, the documentation is very weak for other boards than RPi. So is there anyone who is experienced with creating custom Images for Windows 10 IoT Core?

Edit:

The log shows the following after the command buildimage MyProduct Test

Creating MyProduct Test Image, see C:\iot-adk-addonkit-develop\Build\arm\MyProduct_Test.log for progress
    ThreadId8768 ERROR: Please run imageapp.exe in an elevated console

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for questions about programming problems, not operating system installation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Rob I know, but where else should i ask this question?

Comment: @andy, could you please show the errors or detailed logs when you built the image unsuccessfully?

Comment: I have edited the question with the error in the logfile

Comment: Which version of IoT Core are you using to base the image on?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to build a custom Windows IoT Core Image for Dragonboard 410c.By flashing the FFU on to the image, all of the required software is flashed on to the target at once.You'll need the following software:

•   [Windows 10 Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install)

•   [Windows 10 IoT Core Packages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10iotcore)

•   [IoT ADK Add-on Kit](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit)

•   [Windows 10 IoT Core Board Support Package (BSP) for Dragonboard 410c](https://developer.qualcomm.com/hardware/dragonboard-410c/software)

And it is recommended to setup the image building environment on a clean system.

1. Run `iot-adk-addonkit\IoTCoreShell-arm.cmd`
2. Run `installoemcerts.cmd` to install Test Sign Certificates on the system
3. Run following command to export feature cabs.Assuming C:\a8016aaattnwza21120000.2_db410c_bsp is where the BSP was extracted to.

   C:\iot-adk-addonkit\Tools\bsptools\QCDB410C\export.cmd C:\a8016aaattnwza21120000.2_db410c_bsp\DB410c_BSP
4. Run `newproduct.cmd DemoDevice QCDB410C` and choose to enter SMBIOS data to uniquely identify your device in SMBIOS.
5. Run `buildpkg.cmd all`
6. Unplug all USB storage devices and then run this command to start creating a Test FFU.

   `createimage.cmd DemoDevice Test`

It may take between 10 to 30 min to build an FFU depend on your build system speed. If the process completed without error, you can navigate to `C:\iot-adk-addonkit\Build\arm\DemoDevice\Test` to find the Flash.ffu.
Please node that, the version of WDK, ADK, and the core kit package should remain consistent.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael Xu. When running the toolset on version 1803, everything went fine until the createimage command. There i get the following error: ThreadId8768 ERROR: Please run imageapp.exe in an elevated console.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail log(Flash.ImageApp.log,which in `Build\arm\DemoDevice\Test` folder)? And what are the versions of WDK ,ADK and AddOnKit? I tested with WDK 17137, ADK 17134, AddOnKit 5.1 which is the latest currently.

Comment: Yes i can provide the details as soon as i'm at home. As i saw on github, it seems to be an issue with localization, because i'm not using en-US on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I totally forgot about this, because i hadn't much time to spend in the last months, sorry about that. No with the latest toolset and latest Windows 10 version, everything is working fine. Now i need to build a retail image, but i don't know what i do need for that. I read something about certificates which i need for signing. Do i have to buy them, or is it also possible to build a retail image, with no additional costs?